# Google maps drag rectangle to select markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a rectangle on the google map and detect if any markers are within the bounds of the rectangle.

To draw a rectangle you hold shift key, click and drag.

I have a working sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/dbwPQ/3/

Why does the .contains method only return true if the rectangle is drawn from bottom left to top right or top right to bottom left.

And yet the same area drawn from top left to bottom right or bottom right to top left returns false????

```
                if (boundsSelectionArea.contains(markers[key].position))
            //if (gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat() <= markers[key].position.lat() &&
            //    gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat() >= markers[key].position.lat() && 
            //    gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng() <= markers[key].position.lng() && 
            //    gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng() >= markers[key].position.lng() ) 
            {
                //if(flashMovie !== null && flashMovie !== undefined) {
                console.log("User selected:" + key + ", id:" + markers[key].id);
                //}
            } else {
                //if(flashMovie !== null && flashMovie !== undefined) {
                console.log("User NOT selected:" + key + ", id:" + markers[key].id);
                //} 
            }
```

**UPDATE** this works but i dont know why? http://jsfiddle.net/dbwPQ/4/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the google.maps.Rectangle.getBounds is returning "invalid" bounds

```
key:Vince posn:(53.801279, -1.5485670000000482) out of bnds:((55.45394132943307, -4.0869140625), (52.72298552457069, 1.7138671875))
key:Vince posn:(53.801279, -1.5485670000000482) in bnds:((52.26815737376817, -4.04296875), (55.65279803318956, 2.2412109375))
```

If you extend an empty google.maps.LatLng object with your two corners, it will work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousemove', function (e) {
    if (mouseIsDown && shiftPressed) {
        if (gribBoundingBox !== null) // box exists
        {
            bounds.extend(e.latLng);                
            gribBoundingBox.setBounds(bounds); // If this statement is enabled, I lose mouseUp events

        } else // create bounding box
        {
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend(e.latLng);
            gribBoundingBox = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                map: themap,
                bounds: bounds,
                fillOpacity: 0.15,
                strokeWeight: 0.9,
                clickable: false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_rectangleSelectB.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markers = {};
var bounds = null;
// add marker to object
var posi = new google.maps.LatLng(53.801279, -1.548567);
var name = 'Vince';
markers[name] = {};
markers[name].id = 1;
markers[name].lat = 53.801279;
markers[name].lng = -1.548567;
markers[name].state = 'Online';
markers[name].position = posi;
markers[name].selected = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.801279, -1.548567),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  for (var key in markers) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[key].lat, markers[key].lng),
      map: map
    });
    markers[key].marker = marker;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, key) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(key);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, key));
  }

  // Start drag rectangle to select markers !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  var shiftPressed = false;

  $(window).keydown(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 16) { // shift
      shiftPressed = true;
    }
  }).keyup(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 16) { // shift
      shiftPressed = false;
    }
  });

  var mouseDownPos, gribBoundingBox = null,
    mouseIsDown = 0;
  var themap = map;

  google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    if (mouseIsDown && shiftPressed) {
      if (gribBoundingBox !== null) // box exists
      {
        bounds.extend(e.latLng);
        gribBoundingBox.setBounds(bounds); // If this statement is enabled, I lose mouseUp events

      } else // create bounding box
      {
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(e.latLng);
        gribBoundingBox = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          map: themap,
          bounds: bounds,
          fillOpacity: 0.15,
          strokeWeight: 0.9,
          clickable: false
        });
      }
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousedown', function(e) {
    if (shiftPressed) {

      mouseIsDown = 1;
      mouseDownPos = e.latLng;
      themap.setOptions({
        draggable: false
      });
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mouseup', function(e) {
    if (mouseIsDown && shiftPressed) {
      mouseIsDown = 0;
      if (gribBoundingBox !== null) // box exists
      {
        var boundsSelectionArea = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getSouthWest(), gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getNorthEast());

        for (var key in markers) { // looping through my Markers Collection 

          //                    if (boundsSelectionArea.contains(markers[key].marker.getPosition())) 
          if (gribBoundingBox.getBounds().contains(markers[key].marker.getPosition())) {
            //if(flashMovie !== null && flashMovie !== undefined) {
            markers[key].marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png")
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "key:" + key + " posn:" + markers[key].marker.getPosition() + " in bnds:" + gribBoundingBox.getBounds() + "<br>";
            // console.log("User selected:" + key + ", id:" + markers[key].id);
            //}   
          } else {
            //if(flashMovie !== null && flashMovie !== undefined) {
            markers[key].marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png")
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "key:" + key + " posn:" + markers[key].marker.getPosition() + " out of bnds:" + gribBoundingBox.getBounds() + "<br>";
            // console.log("User NOT selected:" + key + ", id:" + markers[key].id);
            //} 
          }
        }

        gribBoundingBox.setMap(null); // remove the rectangle
      }
      gribBoundingBox = null;

    }

    themap.setOptions({
      draggable: true
    });
    //stopDraw(e);
  });

});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: It didn't work anymore. In my case, I removed themap.setOptions({draggable: false}) from mousedown handler and move it into keydown handler, after this line shiftPressed = true. With that changes, it works.

Comment: By the way, draggable is deprecated. So you could use gestureHandling instead, see more at Google maps reference. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: It works for me (with Chrome on a desktop), shift-mousedown to start the rectangular  selection, mouseup to end

Comment: it works well if you keep a reference to the bounding box with `` and before recreating a new bounding box on mouse move, set map of the previous bounding box to null: `if (this.gripBoundingBox) this.gripBoundingBox.setMap(null);`

Comment: It still works for me in Chrome on a desktop. If you are having issues with it please create a new question with a [mcve] and instructions on how to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 10):

I have some change base on geocodezip's working version.

If you use "extend" of LatLngBounds, it will be only getting bigger but not smaller when you move inside. So I generate LatLngBounds every mouse move to fit my requirement. (It might be optimized in another way I guess.)

**Update:** Found another issue, if user released the shift key before mouse up, the gridbound will stick on the map, fixed it in the following code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousemove', function (e) {
+   if (mouseIsDown && (shiftPressed|| gribBoundingBox != null) ) {
        if (gribBoundingBox !== null) // box exists
        {         
+           var newbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(mouseDownPos,null);
+           newbounds.extend(e.latLng);    
+           gribBoundingBox.setBounds(newbounds); // If this statement is enabled, I lose mouseUp events

        } else // create bounding box
        {
            gribBoundingBox = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                map: themap,
+               bounds: null,
                fillOpacity: 0.15,
                strokeWeight: 0.9,
                clickable: false
            });
        }
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mouseup', function (e) {
+   if (mouseIsDown && (shiftPressed|| gribBoundingBox != null)) {
        mouseIsDown = 0;

    /*........*/
```

- Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ZxMA/4/
- demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/7ZxMA/4/show/

**Update**: 
Found another scenario that you might interested.

use a button to select map. (User could click the "select map" button to select markers or use shift key to select markers.)

- working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ZxMA/6/
- demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/7ZxMA/6/show/

Comment: @tonyq it also breaks when the mouse is over a marker (or other google maps object) any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Thanks for this, just perfect for my project :)

Answer (score 2):

You missuse constructor of the `google.maps.LatLngBounds class`. According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds) you must pass two arguments: south-west and north-east corners. However, sometimes you pass south-east and north-west corners. This probably has impact on `.contains` method.